# How to map a view and a table to one model using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working with SQLAlchemy and Flask for the first time to create an API and I'm trying to do something that I've done many times before in .NET using Entity Framework, which is to create one model for my CRUD operations which combines columns from a view and a table. I'm wondering if it's possible to do, or if what I'm trying to do is not the "right" way to do this in Flask/SQLAlchemy. I'm also using the flask-sqlalchemy library.

Here are two models:

```
class PigeonView(db.Model):
    __table_args__ = {'info': dict(is_view=True)}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pigeon.id')
    kick_events = db.Column(db.Integer)

class PigeonBase(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
```

Pigeon is mapped to a table, PigeonView is mapped to a view (the DB is mySQL).

This is the view:

```
CREATE VIEW pigeon_view AS 
    SELECT 
        p.id AS id, 
        COALESCE(SUM(k.pigeon_id), 0) AS kick_events 
    FROM pigeon p 
    LEFT JOIN kick_event k 
    ON p.Id = k.pigeon_id GROUP BY p.Id
```

Basically, just a pigeon ID and an integer of how many times the pigeon has been kicked.

(There is another model/table called Kick Events where this information is coming from which looks like this)

```
class KickEvent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "kick_event"

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    pigeon_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pigeon.id'), primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

What I would like as an end result is one pigeon model that contains everything from the Pigeon table as well as the kick_events column from the Pigeon view. (And potentially any other variables which are added to the pigeon view).

Something like this:

```
class Pigeon(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True) #from pigeon table
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False) #from pigeon table
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False) #from pigeon table
    kick_events = db.Column(db.Integer) #from pigeon view
```

In .NET / Entity Framework I would do something like this to map these properties to my end-goal Pigeon class:

```
this.HasKey((x => x.Id));

this.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
this.Property(x => x.DateCreated).HasColumnName("DateCreated");
this.Property(x => x.KickEvents).HasColumnName("KickEvents");

Map(m =>
{
    m.Properties(p => new
    {
        p.Id,
        p.Name,
        p.DateCreated
    });
    m.ToTable("Pigeon");
});

Map(m =>
{
    m.Properties(p => new
    {
        p.Id,
        p.KickEvents
    });
    m.ToTable("PigeonView");
});
```

But I'm not sure how to get there with Python/SQLAlchemy as the whole process is obviously very different from Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Upon some further digging I decided to scrap the view entirely, attach Pigeons to KickEvents with a relationship, and add a column property to sum the kicks.

```
class Pigeon(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    kick_events = db.Column(db.Integer)
    kick_events = relationship("KickEvent"),
    kick_count = column_property(
        select([func.count(KickEvent.id)]).\
            where(KickEvent.pigeon_id==id).\
            correlate_except(KickEvent))
```

(Not super relevant to the solution but I also modified KickEvents to have an Id which serves as the primary key because I decided I wanted a user to be able to kick the same pigeon more than once, so that's why I'm able to do count on the KickEvent.Id which is a column not in my original code)

I guess this doesn't really answer the question I posed, since I'm not combining a table and a view, but having gotten rid of the view completely I still have the end result I wanted which is a single model containing the Pigeon table and a value computed based on a table with a relation to Pigeon (KickEvent).

Picked up all this from here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html

I hope this helps anyone looking into the same issue. Also if I've gone about this totally the wrong way, please tell me. I would love to know if there's a better way.